# Matching if not exact

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

Can you help since I can't work out a methodical approach for following problem.

Following xml documents has set person records grouped by Id. I wanted to search for a node, conditionally based on two other attributes (MinAge,MaxAge). All works fine and I can search for a specific node based on Id and Age parameters.

```
    <Group Id="189" Description="189 T1" MinAge="20" MaxAge="30"/>
    <Group Id="189" Description="189 T2" MinAge="31" MaxAge="40"/>
    <Group Id="190" Description="190 T1" MinAge="20" MaxAge="30"/>
    <Group Id="190" Description="190 T2" MinAge="35" MaxAge="45"/>
    <Group Id="190" Description="190 T3" MinAge="49" MaxAge="50"/>
    <Group Id="191" Description="191 T1" MinAge="20" MaxAge="30"/>
    <Group Id="193" Description="193 T1" MinAge="18" MaxAge="50"/>

var allGroup = XDocument.Parse("xml string");

        var specificGroup =
            allGroup.Descendants("Group").Where(e => e.Attribute("Id").Value == Id &&
            int.Parse(e.Attribute("MinAge").Value) >= Age &&
            int.Parse(e.Attribute("MaxAge").Value) <= Age)
```

**Question**: What I want is to return one closely matching node if there is no exact matching found.
I.e, 
Assume if I have a search condition where Id=189 and Age is 35, then the output node will be the one with Description '189 T2'. This is fine and is exactly matched.

Now assume if I have a search condition where Id=190 and Age is 34, then there won't be any output node since there is no matching record. But here,

> I wanted to return a node with Description '190 T2', which is closely
>   matched though it is not exact match.

Comment: @Jodrell, Sorry. Not sure what you really means by that phrase

Comment: You first need to define the search criteria. What do you want returned for (100,51) - should be be "189 T2" - which is closest in the first term, or "193 T1" - which is closer in the 2nd term?

Comment: Why can't you change the MinAge attribute to include your expected minimum age? If you need another list containing close matches, then you could add a CloseMatchYears attribute to the Plan tag, which contains the number of years where a close match can apply in case of no exact match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just some classical algorithm:

```
int target = 190; // target find value
int min = int.MaxValue;
Node best = null;
foreach (var node in nodes) {
   int num = getNum(node.Describtion); // get the number from string
   if (Math.Abs(target - num) < min) {
     min = Math.Abs(target - num);
     best = node;
   }
}
```

This will lead you to the exact match (`min == 0` in this case), or if not found, to the nearest age (either greater or smaller). The result *best* node will be in `best` variable.

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of convoluted, but this one should do what you want.

```css
var specificGroup = (allGroup.Descendants("Group").Where(e => e.Attribute("Id").Value == Id && int.Parse(e.Attribute("MinAge").Value) <= Age && int.Parse(e.Attribute("MaxAge").Value) >= Age).Any()) 
      ? allGroup.Descendants("Group").Where(e => e.Attribute("Id").Value == Id && int.Parse(e.Attribute("MinAge").Value) <= Age && int.Parse(e.Attribute("MaxAge").Value) >= Age)
      : (allGroup.Descendants("Group").Where(e => e.Attribute("Id").Value == Id).Any())
      ? allGroup.Descendants("Group").Where(e => e.Attribute("Id").Value == Id).min(Math.Abs(Age - int.Parse(e.Attribute("MinAge").Value))+ Math.Abs(Age-int.Parse(e.Attribute("MaxAge").Value)))
      : (allGroup.Descendants("Group").Where(e => int.Parse(e.Attribute("MinAge").Value) <= Age && int.Parse(e.Attribute("MaxAge").Value >= Age)).min(Math.Abs(Id - e.Id))).Any()
      ? allGroup.Descendants("Group").Where(e => int.Parse(e.Attribute("MinAge").Value) <= Age && int.Parse(e.Attribute("MaxAge").Value >= Age)).min(Math.Abs(Id - e.Id))
      : allGroup.Descendants("Group").min(e => .min(Math.Abs(Age - int.Parse(e.Attribute("MinAge").Value))+ Math.Abs(Age-int.Parse(e.Attribute("MaxAge").Value)) + Math.Abs(Id - e.Id)));
```